# How can I compare array value in my menu list and add a class with match value tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add a class on the tag that is matched with the array value. I have a menu list that contains 150 lists so that I need to add a class to the tag that text match with an array value.

```
<ul class="nav main" id="tabs">
    <li class="menu-list mn">
         <a class="ac" href="">
            <span><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> Purchase</span>
         </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-list">
            <li id="menu110">
                <a href="" class="showkey purchase" ><span>Enter Purchase Invoice</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
var nwArray=["Enter Purchase Invoice"]
$('#tabs li ul li a span').each(function (index) {

  
    var nwVal = $(this).text().trim();
    var nwVal2 = nwArray[index];

    if ($(this+":contains('" + nwVal2 + "')")) {
        $(this).addClass('show');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `:contains` directly with `this` you have to combine it with `is` like the example below:

```
if ($(this).is(":contains('" + nwVal2 + "')")) {
  $(this).addClass('show');
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var nwArray = ["Enter Purchase Invoice"]
$('#tabs li ul li a span').each(function(index) {


  var nwVal = $(this).text().trim();
  var nwVal2 = nwArray[index];

  if ($(this).is(":contains('" + nwVal2 + "')")) {
    $(this).addClass('show');
  }

});
```

```css
.show {
  font-size: 40px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav main" id="tabs">
  <li class="menu-list mn" id="menudb"><a href="dashboards/BasicDashboard.aspx" class="showkey dshboard" onclick="checkoption('dashboard')"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>  <span>Dashboard </span> </a></li>
  <li class="menu-list mn select"><a class="ac" href=""><span><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> Purchase</span></a>

    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
      <li id="menu110"><a href="purchase.aspx?pageName=PurchaseMaster" class="showkey purchase" onclick="checkoption('purchase')"><span>Enter Purchase Invoice</span></a></li>
      <li id="menu123"><a href="purchase.aspx?pageName=PurchaseOrderMaster" class="showkey purchase" onclick="checkoption('purchase')"><span>Create Purchase Order</span> </a></li>
      <li class="menu-list" id="Li124">
        <a href="Reports/PurchaseOrderList.aspx?pageName=PurchaseOrderMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Purchase Order Report</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li11"><a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection.aspx?pageName=PurcheseItemList" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"><span>Purchase Item Selection</span></a></li>
      <li class="menu-list mn">
        <a class="ac notlink" href=""><span> Purchase Import</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-list">
          <li id="Li20">
            <a href="purchaseimport.aspx?pageName=PurchaseMasterImport" onclick="checkoption('purchase')" class="showkey purchase"> <span>Enter Import Invoice</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li id="Li40">
            <a href="Reports/imports.aspx" onclick="checkoption('purchase')" class="showkey purchase"> <span>Enter Additional Cost</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li id="Li42">
            <a href="Reports/importInvoices.aspx" onclick="checkoption('purchase')" class="showkey purchase"> <span>Additional Cost Detail</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li id="Li48">
            <a href="Reports/importdetail.aspx" onclick="checkoption('purchase')" class="showkey purchase"> <span>Import Invoice Detail</span> </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list" id="menu371e"><a href="Accounting/Purchase_Overhead.aspx?pageName=Purchase_Overhead" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"><span>Purchase Overhead</span> </a></li>
      <li class="menu-list mn">
        <a class="ac notlink" href=""><span> Debit Note</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-list">
          <li id="Li34">
            <a href="purchase.aspx?pageName=DebitNoteMaster" onclick="checkoption('purchase')" class="showkey purchase"> <span>Goods Return</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li id="Li60">
            <a href="purchase.aspx?pageName=DebitNoteMaster&amp;type=1" onclick="checkoption('purchase')" class="showkey purchase"> <span>Rate Discount</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li id="Li61">
            <a href="purchase.aspx?pageName=DebitNoteMaster&amp;type=2" onclick="checkoption('purchase')" class="showkey purchase"> <span>General Discount</span> </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="menu-list mn wth67"><a class="ac" href=""><span><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> Sale </span></a>

    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
      <li id="Li43">
        <a href="sale.aspx?pageName=QuotationMaster" class="showkey sale" onclick="checkoption('sale')"> <span>Generate Quotation</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li65">
        <a href="sale.aspx?pageName=PerfomaMaster" class="showkey sale" onclick="checkoption('sale')"> <span>Generate Perfoma</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li355423">
        <a href="sale.aspx?pageName=SaleOrderMaster" class="showkey sale" onclick="checkoption('sale')"> <span>Generate Sale Order</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu521">
        <a href="sale.aspx?pageName=SaleMaster" class="showkey sale" onclick="checkoption('sale f8')"> <span>Generate Sale Invoice</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li45">
        <a href="sale.aspx?pageName=EstimateMaster" class="showkey sale" onclick="checkoption('sale')"> <span>Generate Challan</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li131"><a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection.aspx?pageName=SaleItemList" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"><span>Sale Item Selection</span></a> </li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="menu381f"><a href="Accounting/Purchase_Overhead.aspx?pageName=Sales_Overhead" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"><span>Sales Overhead</span> </a></li>
      <li class="menu-list mn">
        <a class="ac notlink" href=""><span>Credit Note</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-list">
          <li id="Li62">
            <a href="sale.aspx?pageName=CreditNoteMaster" onclick="checkoption('sale')" class="showkey sale"> <span>Goods Return</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li id="Li63">
            <a href="sale.aspx?pageName=CreditNoteMaster&amp;type=1" onclick="checkoption('sale')" class="showkey sale"> <span>Rate Discount</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li id="Li64">
            <a href="sale.aspx?pageName=CreditNoteMaster&amp;type=2" onclick="checkoption('sale')" class="showkey sale"> <span>General Discount</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li id="Li64">
            <a href="sale.aspx?pageName=CreditNoteMaster&amp;type=3" onclick="checkoption('sale')" class="showkey sale"> <span>Invoice Wise</span> </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list mn">
    <a class="ac213" href=""><span><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Production </span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
      <li id="Li2bcsd1">
        <a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection3.aspx?pageName=ItemProduction" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Production Action</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li1bcdf2">
        <a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection3.aspx?pageName=ItemConsumption" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Consumption Variation Transaction</span> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list mn hidden">
    <a class="ac" href=""><span> Import</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
      <li id="Li13"><a href="purchaseimport.aspx?pageName=PurchaseMasterImport" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"><span>Enter Import Invoice</span></a></li>
      <li id="Li14">
        <a href="Reports/imports.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Enter Additional Cost</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li6">
        <a href="Reports/importInvoices.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Additional Cost Detail</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li49">
        <a href="Reports/importdetail.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Import Invoice Detail </span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list mn">
    <a class="ac" href=""><span><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Barcode </span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
      <li id="Li2bc1">
        <a href="barcode-master.aspx" onclick="checkoption('barcode')" class="showkey barcode"> <span>Generate Barcode (Format 1)</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li1bc2">
        <a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection.aspx?pageName=Barcode_master" onclick="checkoption('barcode')" class="showkey barcode"> <span>Generate Barcode (Format 2)</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li3adsf2314l">
        <a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection.aspx?pageName=OpeningStock" onclick="checkoption('barcode')" class="showkey barcode"> <span>Generate Barcode (Format 3)</span> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list mn">
    <a class="ac" href=""> <span><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> Supplier</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
      <li class="menu-list " id="Li2">
        <a href="suplier-master.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>New Supplier / Master</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li10">
        <a href="transaction/PaymentApplied.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Payment </span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li19">
        <a href="transaction/PaymentAdjustment.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Payment Adjustment </span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li18">
        <a href="transaction/PaymentList.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Payment List </span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="L43i25">
        <a href="transaction/PaymentListPDC.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Payment List PDC</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="Li4">
        <a href="transaction/SupplierBalanceReport.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Supplier Balance Report </span> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list mn">
    <a class="ac" href=""><span><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Customer</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
      <li class="menu-list " id="Li17">
        <a href="General_Masters/Customer_master.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>New Customer / Masters</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li21">
        <a href="transaction/SalesPaymentApplied.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Receipt </span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li23">
        <a href="transaction/SalesPaymentAdjustment.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Receipt Adjustment </span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li26">
        <a href="transaction/SalesPaymentList.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Receipt List </span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li2adsf5" class="">
        <a href="transaction/SalesPaymentListPDC.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Receipt List PDC</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li27">
        <a href="transaction/SupplierBalanceReport.aspx?pageName=CustomerMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Customer Balance Report </span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li28a2">
        <a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection3.aspx?pageName=DiscountMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>MRP Mapping</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li28a3">
        <a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection3.aspx?pageName=PriceMapping" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Discount Price Mapping</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li27a1">
        <a href="General_Masters/CustomerCategoryMaster.aspx?pageName=CustomerCategoryMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Customer Category Master</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li27a2">
        <a href="General_Masters/BrandMaster.aspx?pageName=DiscountNameMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Discount Master</span> </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list mn">
    <a class="ac" href=""><span><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Accounting </span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
      <li class="menu-list " id="menu391g">
        <a href="finance/supven.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Create Ledger A/c</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="Li39">
        <a href="finance/acgps.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Create Group </span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="menu401h"><a href="finance/suppvenedit.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"><span> Modify / delete Ledger A/c</span> </a></li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="Li5"><a href="finance/LedgerMerge.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"><span> Merge Ledger A/c</span> </a></li>

      <li class="menu-list " id="Li3kk123">
        <a href="bankrecon.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Bank Reconciliation</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="Li4kk12321">
        <a href="bankreconalter.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Modify Bank Reconciliation</span> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list mn" id="menudb1"><a href="finance/journal.aspx"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>  <span>Journal Entries</span> </a></li>
  <li class="menu-list mn">
    <a class="ac" href=""> <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Admin </span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
      <li id="MainMenu6">
        <a href="newUser.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Create New User</span> </a>
      </li>

      <li id="MainMenu8">
        <a href="adminsettings/UserAuthorization.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>User Autorization</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li30">
        <a href="datelock.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Date Lock</span> </a>
      </li>


      <li id="MainMenu11">
        <a href="ClientUpdate.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Company Profile</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="MainMenu11">
        <a href="General_Masters/termsCondition.aspx?pageName=TermsCondition" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Terms &amp; Conditions</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li67">
        <a href="prints/ReportSettings.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Print Format Setting</span> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list mn wth67">
    <a href="" class="ac"> <span><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Master</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
      <li class="menu-list ">
        <a href="" class="notlink"> General Setting </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-list">

          <li class="menu-list " id="Li170">
            <a href="General_Masters/BrandMaster.aspx?pageName=Size_master" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Size2 Master</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list " id="Li171">
            <a href="General_Masters/BrandMaster.aspx?pageName=Unit_master" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Unit Master</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list " id="Li35jkh">
            <a href="General_Masters/BrandMaster.aspx?pageName=Cat_master" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Category Master  </span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list " id="Ljkhi36">
            <a href="General_Masters/BrandMaster.aspx?pageName=SubCategory_master" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Sub-Category Master  </span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="MainMenu20"><a href="General_Masters/SelectionMaster.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> Selection Master / Creation</a></li>

      <li id="item1">
        <a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection3.aspx?pageName=ItemMapping_master&amp;refpage=Produced_Goods" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Item Standard Qty Mapping</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="item13">
        <a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection3.aspx?pageName=standard_produced_items" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Item Packing Qty Mapping</span> </a>
      </li>


      <li class="menu-list " id="menu29">
        <a href="hsn-master.aspx?pageName=Hsn_master" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>HSN Master</span> </a>
      </li>


      <li class="menu-list " id="MainMenu21"><a href="General_Masters/ItemCreations.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> Item Creation</a></li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="Li125">
        <a href="DocumentNo.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Document Creation </span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="Li9"><a href="General_Masters/BankNameMaster.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> Bank Name Master</a></li>
      <li id="Li8s">
        <a href="General_Masters/Consignee_master.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Consignee / Branch Master</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li68">
        <a href="General_Masters/Employee.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Employee Master</span> </a>
        <!--
                              <li id="Li265"-->
        <a href="General_Masters/EmployeeDesignation.aspx?pageName=EmployeeDesignation" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Employee Designation Master</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li id="Li69">
        <a href="General_Masters/BrandMaster.aspx?PageName=EmployeeDepartMent" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Employee Department Master</span> </a>
      </li>

      <li class="menu-list hidden"><a href="" onclick="checkoption('noshow')">Price Structure<i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-list">
          <li class="menu-list " id="Li41">
            <a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelection.aspx?pageName=item_customer_price_mapping" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Price Structure Customer Wise</span> </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list hidden" id="Li7">
        <a href="Reports/pricemappingitemwise.aspx?pageName=item_customer_price_mapping_itemwise" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Price Structure Item Wise</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list hidden" id="menu2548">
        <a href="Reports/itemListPurchaseSelectionqty.aspx?pageName=ItemMapping_master" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Item Standard Qty Mapping</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="Li47">
        <a href="LoyaltyMaster/mail_setting.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Email Master</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="Li54">
        <a href="LoyaltyMaster/loyaltyPoints_master.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Cashback / Promotional Schemes</span> </a>
      </li>

      <li class="menu-list " id="menu34">
        <a href="commission-master.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Incentive Master</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list select" id="menu21">
        <a href="General_Masters/loyaltyPoints_master.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Loyalty Points Master </span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list" id="menu22">
        <a href="General_Masters/AgeingDaysMaster.aspx?pageName=AgeingDays" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Ageing Days Master </span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list mn hidden">
    <a href="" class="ac"> <span>Promotion</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-list">


      <li class="menu-list " id="m2">
        <a href="LoyaltyMaster/prepaid_master.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Prepaid  master</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list " id="m3">
        <a href="LoyaltyMaster/prepaid_master2.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Prepaid Pack Assign</span> </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="menu-list mn">
    <a href="" class="ac"><span><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Reports</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-list w151">
      <li class="menu-list ">
        <a href="" class="notlink"> General Reports <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-list w165 m50">
          <li class="menu-list " id="MainMenu26">
            <a href="Reports/ItemList.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Item Report</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list " id="Li71">
            <a href="Reports/ItemList2.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>All Item Report</span> </a>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-list"><a href="" class="notlink"><span>Purchase Report <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu-list m50">

              <li class="menu-list " id="Li33">
                <a href="Reports/PurchaseList.aspx?pageName=PurchaseMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Purchase Invoice Report</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li25">
                <a href="Reports/Generalist.aspx?pageName=purchase items reports" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Purchase Item Report</span> </a>
              </li>

              <li class="menu-list " id="Li1">
                <a href="Reports/PurchaseOrderList.aspx?pageName=PurchaseOrderMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Purchase Order Report</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li1342">
                <a href="Reports/Generalist.aspx?pageName=purchaseorder items reports" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Purchase Order Item Report</span> </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list "><a href="" class="notlink"><span>Sale Report <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu-list m50">

              <li class="menu-list " id="Li121">
                <a href="Reports/SaleList.aspx?pageName=SaleList" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Sale Report</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li301">
                <a href="Reports/Generalist.aspx?pageName=sale item report" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Sale Item Report</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li344">
                <a href="Reports/TempInvoiceList.aspx?pageName=SaleOrderMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Sale Order Invoice Report</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li12">
                <a href="Reports/Generalist.aspx?pageName=saleorder item report" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Sale Order Item Report</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li44">
                <a href="reports/InvList.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Invoice Tracking Report</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li46">
                <a href="reports/TempInvoiceList.aspx?pageName=EstimateMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Challan Invoice Report</span> </a>
              </li>

              <li class="menu-list " id="L123i19">
                <a href="reports/TempInvoiceList.aspx?pageName=QuotationMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Quotation Invoice Report</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li66">
                <a href="reports/TempInvoiceList.aspx?pageName=PerfomaMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Perfoma Invoice Report</span> </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>



          <li class="menu-list"><a href="" class="notlink"><span>Credit Note Report <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu-list m50">

              <li class="menu-list " id="Li22">
                <a href="Reports/CreditNoteList.aspx?pageName=CreditNoteMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Credit Note Invoice Wise</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li28">
                <a href="Reports/Generalist.aspx?pageName=credit note item report" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Credit Note Item Wise</span> </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list"><a href="" class="notlink"><span>Debit Note Report <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu-list m50">
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li24">
                <a href="Reports/DebitNoteList.aspx?pageName=DebitNoteMaster" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Debit Note Invoice Wise</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li29">
                <a href="Reports/Generalist.aspx?pageName=Debit note item report" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Debit Note Item Wise</span> </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list hidden" id="Li70">
            <a href="Reports/EmployeeList.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Employee List</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list " id="Li20adsf3">
            <a href="Reports/produced_goods_standard.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Item Standard Qty Mapping Report</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list " id="Li20adsf3">
            <a href="Reports/BarcodeList.aspx?pageName=Barcode_master" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Barcode Report</span> </a>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-list"><a href="" class="notlink"><span>Profit/Margin Report <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu-list m50">
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li8">
                <a href="Reports/Generalist1.aspx?pageName=MarginReport" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Profit Margin Invoice Wise</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li50">
                <a href="Reports/Generalist1.aspx?pageName=MarginReportItem" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Profit Margin Item Wise</span> </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list "><a href="" class="notlink"><span>Commission Report <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu-list m50">
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li52">
                <a href="Reports/Generalist1.aspx?pageName=CommInvWise" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Commission Invoice Wise</span> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-list " id="Li53">
                <a href="Reports/Generalist1.aspx?pageName=CommItemWise" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Commission Item Wise</span> </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>


          <li class="menu-list  select" id="Li51">
            <a href="Reports/custpaymentform.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Balance Payment Report</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list " id="Li55">
            <a href="Reports/stockreportoffer.aspx" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>CashBack Offer Report</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-list select" id="Li1736">
            <a href="Reports/Generalist.aspx?pageName=loyalty points report" onclick="checkoption('noshow')"> <span>Loyalty Points Report</span> </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLSpanElement]:contains('Enter Purchase Invoice') i got error when apply the code

Comment: Works fine in the snippet, are you sure the html is the same?

Comment: http://erp4biz.com/menulist.html here i have add all link please check

Comment: @user3090653 I've add almost all your html, (it was to long for snippet to accept) but it works fine with your html

Comment: if (($(this).text()+":contains('" + nwVal2 + "')")) This code work in my application thank you for help